# mysql - Find parent with child

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
parent{
    parent_id
}

child{
    child_id
    parent_id
}
```

I need to find a parent with parameters are children id

Ex: Find a parent has exactly children (1, 2, 3)

I tried "Where child_id IN (1, 2, 3)" but it will return incorrect parent in case parent has children(1, 2, 3, 4)

I can hard code with php but I ask for mysql solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a COUNT() condition, if a parent has (1,2,3) for children and 3 children it's all good !

```
SELECT *
FROM parent NATURAL JOIN child
WHERE child.child_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY parent.parent_id
HAVING COUNT(child.child_id) = 3
```

(not tested)

Comment: hope this may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-parent-child-relationship-in-an-effective-and-easy-way

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
SELECT parent_id, child_id, count(child_id) as n, sum(child_id) as m FROM child
group by parent_id
HAVING child_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND n = 3 AND m = 6
```