# Get the top 3 commentator from a table in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have 3 tables

```
comments(id,question_id, user_Id) // here the user_id is of the user who has asked the question
questions(id,q_desc, user_id)
users(id, name, rank)
```

A user can ask question and can comment on the questions.

I need a report in which I want to display every question with at most 3 top ranked user, who have commented on it, **but the user who has asked the question should not be in the report for that particular question, but he too has the privilege to comment on his question.**

EDited:::

```
Select * from comments inner join users(comments.user_id=u.id) group by question_id order by user.rank desc
```

Comment: @Nerd-Herd: I didn't add my query then, because I am having the problem in starting this, because the problem lies in the top 3 ranked users for each question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's messy but it works:

```
SELECT 
    a.question_id, a.user_id, a.name, a.rank
FROM
(
    SELECT a.*, b.name, b.rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT b.question_id, b.user_id
        FROM questions a
        INNER JOIN comments b ON a.id = b.question_id AND a.user_id <> b.user_id
    ) a
    INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.question_id, b.rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT b.question_id, b.user_id
        FROM questions a
        INNER JOIN comments b ON a.id = b.question_id AND a.user_id <> b.user_id
    ) a
    INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id
) b ON a.question_id = b.question_id AND a.rank <= b.rank
GROUP BY 
    a.question_id, a.user_id, a.name, a.rank
HAVING 
    COUNT(1) <= 3
ORDER BY 
    a.question_id, a.rank DESC
```

**EDIT**: This produces the same results and is more succinct:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT a.question_id, a.user_id, b.name, b.rank
   FROM comments a
   INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id
) a
INNER JOIN 
    questions b ON a.question_id = b.id AND a.user_id <> b.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT a.question_id, a.user_id, b.rank
   FROM comments a
   INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id
) c ON b.id = c.question_id AND a.rank <= c.rank
GROUP BY 
    a.question_id, a.user_id, a.name, a.rank
HAVING 
    COUNT(1) <= 3
ORDER BY 
    a.question_id, a.rank DESC;
```

These solutions also account for users that have posted more than one comment in the same question.

See both solutions in action at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c091/27/1)

Comment: Excellent Zane, I am accepting your answer, can you please help me in the hierarchy issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-in-a-less-number-of-mysql-queries

Comment: @SashiKant, Thanks! By the way, I just made a more succinct version of the solution if you're interested. See revised answer.