# How to create hierarchical tree structure and also inner join operation with another table using recursive query a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, codeigniter

Consider this MySQL table:

Table 1

[image]

For MySQL versions that do not support Common Table Expressions (up to version 5.7), you could achieve this with the following query:

```
select  id,
        username,
        sponser_id
from    (select * from db_users
         order by sponser_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '5') initialisation
where   find_in_set(sponser_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id));
```

**I want to modify this query to perform inner join operations with another table.**

Table 2
For table 2 you can take any example:

Answer (score 0):

**try this for recursion...**  **reference:**[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497202/get-all-child-grandchild-etc-nodes-under-parent-using-php-with-mysql-query-resu)

```
function recursiveCheck($src_arr, $parent_id=0, $tree = array())
{
    foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row)
    {
        if($row['parent_id'] == $parent_id)
        {
            foreach($row as $k => $v)
                $tree[$row['user_id']][$k] = $v;
            unset($src_arr[$idx]);
            $tree[$row['user_id']]['children'] = $this->recursiveCheck($src_arr, $row['user_id']);
        }
    }
    ksort($tree);
    return $tree;
}

$query = "Select * From tablename";

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($data,$row);
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r(recursiveCheck($data));
echo '</pre>';
```

**and for inner join you can do**

```
SELECT
select_list
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON join_condition1
INNER JOIN t3 ON join_condition2
...;
```

check [enter link description here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)