# query for selectiong parents and child

Tags: mysql

I am having one category table where i want to give category for posts

post_category(cat_id,cat_name,parent_id,cat_count)

```
cat_id    cat_name       parent_id       cat_count
   1           C            NULL           300 
   2         Pointers        1             100
   3         Structures      1             200
   4          Java          NULL           700    
   5         Exceptions      5             200
   6         Threading       5             300
   7         Thread Priority 6             200
```

here cat_id is primary key and parent id for root elenemts are null and for child parent id is any valid cat_id.
I want to select each parent and its child details. as follows

```
      C
         Pointers
         Structures    

      Java
         Exceptions
         Threading 
             Thread priority
```

Comment: Have you considered the [nested set model](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/)? It might be worth it if your tree gets deeper. (How do you order siblings at the moment?)

Comment: @DCoder nesting level is only 2

Comment: you should go for some server-side coding also along with Mysql.

Comment: hope this may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-parent-child-relationship-in-an-effective-and-easy-way

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support a variable number of JOINs, as MS SQL (and I think Postgres?) do. However, if you are willing to re-evaluate the schema, there has been some good thinking on the matter, and there are several good options in [this presentation by Bill Karwin at Percona](http://www.percona.tv/percona-webinars/models-for-hierarchical-data-in-sql-and-php)

As it stands, you have essentially two options:

1. Choose an arbitrary depth to query to
2. Select every single record and do the aggregation in your application layer (ick!)

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL I think you'd need to use [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
So perhaps that might help find what you're looking for in the MySQL space.