# SQL - Select to correlate record

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

I have the following table called Tracking:

```
ID_path -- step_start -- step_end -- time  
  1         A             B      10  
  1         B             C      20  
  1         C             D      30  
  2         A             C      100  
  3         D             C      20  
  3         A             N      300
```

I'm looking for a single query in Mysql that can extract the cumulate value for path A-C, so itself and all step inside: [A-C] + [A-B] + [B-C].

> Select sum(time) from tracking where (step_start = 'A' or step_end = 'C') and ID_path = ID_path

I thought this query considering that the value of step can't be both in start and end but I don't know how to express the last condition (ID_path = ID_path) in order to extract only the record that have the same id_path.
Is there a specific SQL function?

Thanks for any help / mysql coding guidelines / advice

Comment: I think you should refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-in-a-less-number-of-mysql-queries

Comment: @SashiKant What does this have to do with hierarchy?

Comment: @Barmar: If you go through the question the requirement is nearly same

Comment: That question has nothing to do with summing anything, it's about turning a parent-child table into PHP nested arrays.

Comment: @SashiKant It seems like your recommendation would be better in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392648/php-nested-array-from-sql-repeating-results

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

```
Select ID_path,sum(time)
from tracking 
where (step_start = 'A' or step_end = 'C')
group by ID_path
```

## [SQl fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25478/3)

Comment: Thanks Joe but I need the final value in the example it's 130 (100 from A-C and 30 grouping A-B and B-c.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I suspect this is it:

```
SELECT id_path, sum(time) total
WHERE step_start = 'A' OR step_end = 'C'
GROUP BY id_path
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar but I need the final value, in the example it's 130 (100 from A-C and 30 grouping A-B and B-c).

Comment: Can there be longer paths, like A-B, B-D, D-E, E-F, F-C?

Comment: Yes but in the same path the step can be included only 1 at start and at end, like train path.

Comment: This is difficult to do in SQL, because it requires an iterative or recursive algorithm to find the complete path. Can you move it into the calling application?

Comment: If there isn't other solution I must use some php script to iterate :-)