# MySQL Query for Parent Child relationship

Tags: mysql

I want to write a select query to get the complete path from child to parent as:

```
| Unique Id | Child Code | Parent Code |
|     X     |     9      |     7       |
|     Y     |     7      |     6       |
|     Z     |     6      |     5       |
|     A     |     5      |    NULL     |
|     B     |     11     |     33      |
|     C     |     33     |     22      |
|     D     |     22     |    NULL     |
```

if code selected is 9 then query should return its all the parents as result which are : 9-7-6-5....

and if code selected is 11 then query should return: 11-33-22....

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use recursive stored procedure. Try it it will work for you

Comment: Does this article help: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: actually i am trying to implement it through query only.

Comment: if you dont want to use stored procedure query multiple times until you get a null

Comment: possible duplicate ::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-in-a-less-number-of-mysql-queries

Comment: [This article might help](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/)

Comment: you can use acl like tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := parent_code FROM mytable WHERE unique_id = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 9, @l := 0) vars,
        mytable m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN mytable T2
ON T1._id = T2.id
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

With `NULL` Parent Value:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY COALESCE(<parent_id>,<id>), <id>), category_parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

With `ZERO` Parent Value:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY COALESCE((SELECT NULLIF(<parent_id>,0)), <id>), NULLIF(<parent_id>,0) IS NOT NULL
```