# Find Nodes in SQL Tree Structure

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a tree-like data model stored in a MYSQL database.  The tree is traversed by using two fields on each 'node' object:

- id
- parent_id

The root id has a parent_id of 'null' and all other nodes in the tree reference a parent id.

If I want to get a list of all node ids in this tree, I have to recursively traverse the tree and collect one or more attributes of each node, using what is essentially a for loop with many queries.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this all more efficiently with on query in SQL

Comment: Hope this one help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-in-a-less-number-of-mysql-queries

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a highly-rated post about a solution I call Closure Table: [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)

I also cover that design in my presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) and in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

And I've answered questions about hierarchical-data queries many times on Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A20860+%5Bhierarchical-data%5D

[Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) has written an epic series of blog articles about querying trees in MySQL:
http://explainextended.com/2009/07/22/hierarchial-queries-in-mysql-identifying-trees/

Quassnoi has also answered a number of questions on Stack Overflow about hierarchical-data:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A55159+%5Bhierarchical-data%5D

Answer (score 1):

You are using a difficult model for searching, the Adjacency List Model.  If you know the number of potential "levels" of parent-to-child relationships you will have, then yes, you can construct a query to do so.  However, if it's not a finite number, then it's going to be pretty difficult.

Consider using the Nested Set Model if possible.  Here is a good article on the subject:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Back to your question, you would have to join on the same table multiple times to get your desired results, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
    LEFT JOIN YourTable t2 ON t2.parentid = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN YourTable t3 ON t3.parentid = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN YourTable t4 ON t4.parentid = t3.id
```

With an additional JOIN for each potential child-parent relationship.

Hope this helps and good luck.