# Many-to-many multi level queries

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a table called "obj_rels" where I have have fields such as:

```
pri_type
pri_type_id
sec_type
sec_type_id
```

The type represents the table the relationship is in. For example COM for comment, FIL for file, SBM for submission or ENT for entity. 
I want to know the entity for each object type.  For example,

Let's say I have a comment (#4) on a file (#3) uploaded to respond to a submission (#2) for entity (#1).  The obj_rels table would have:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| pri_type | pri_type_id | sec_type | sec_type_id |
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| COM      | 4           | FIL      | 3           |
| SBM      | 2           | FIL      | 3           |
| SBM      | 2           | ENT      | 1           |
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

There is no logic to Primary and Secondary entry, so it needs to look at both sides to find a match.  How can I write a query that would dig back into the relationships to find the "ENT" associated with the "COM"?

The one I've written repeats a union query five times, thinking I probably won't have more than 5 levels ever, but it is extremely slow.  I only have about 9k records in the table, and it takes over 30 seconds to run the query.

What is best practice for this type of relationship search?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Nodes in SQL Tree Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656573/find-nodes-in-sql-tree-structure)

Comment: There are zillions of questions about querying arbitrary hierarchy depths in MySQL correctly (store procedures, soon CTEs in 8.0) & incorrectly (read & update a variable in one query, undefined behaviour).