# MySQL Sort Groups of rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, foreign-keys, sql-order-by, hierarchical-data

I have a table *menu* which contains rows which refers to others rows in the same table via foreign keys.
Here the table:

```
+----+---------------+--------+
| id | title         | parent |
+----+---------------+--------+
| 1  | Enseignements | NULL   |
| 2  | Juments       | 4      |
| 3  | Étalons       | 4      |
| 4  | Animaux       | NULL   |
| 5  | Tarifs        | 1      |
+----+---------------+--------+
```

I would like to group rows according to hierarchical and alphabetical order, like this:

```
+----+---------------+--------+
| id | title         | parent |
+----+---------------+--------+
| 4  | Animaux       | NULL   |
| 3  | Étalons       | 4      |
| 2  | Juments       | 4      |
| 1  | Enseignements | NULL   |
| 5  | Tarifs        | 1      |
+----+---------------+--------+
```

I just managed to group items from the same branch. The sub-level items are sorted by *title*. In fact, I wish that all the first-level items are also sorted by *title*, like this:

```
+----+---------------+--------+
| id | title         | parent |
+----+---------------+--------+
| 1  | Enseignements | NULL   |
| 5  | Tarifs        | 1      |
| 4  | Animaux       | NULL   |
| 3  | Étalons       | 4      |
| 2  | Juments       | 4      |
+----+---------------+--------+
```

With the code :

```
SELECT title, COALESCE(parent, id), parent
FROM menu
GROUP BY COALESCE(parent, id), title
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: May be this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-parent-child-relationship-in-an-effective-and-easy-way
help

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4368/12)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(13), `parent` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `title`, `parent`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Enseignements', NULL),
    (2, 'Juments', '4'),
    (3, 'Étalons', '4'),
    (4, 'Animaux', NULL),
    (5, 'Tarifs', '1')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT title, COALESCE(parent, id), parent
FROM Table1
GROUP BY 2,1
order by COALESCE(parent, id) desc,title asc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4368/12/0)**:

```
|         TITLE | COALESCE(PARENT, ID) | PARENT |
-------------------------------------------------
|       Animaux |                    4 | (null) |
|       Étalons |                    4 |      4 |
|       Juments |                    4 |      4 |
| Enseignements |                    1 | (null) |
|        Tarifs |                    1 |      1 |
```