# using outer join in mysql to join child tables

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have a newbie question about outer joins. I have 5 tables with the following structure.

```
employee (employee_id, name, address)
employee_benefits (employee_id, benefit_id, join_date)
insurance (insurance_id, name)
insurance_benefits (insurance_id, benefit_id)
benefit (benefit_id, title)
```

For a selected employee, I need to select all insurances with benefits matching either the full or partial set of benefits available to employees. 
Example:

```
benefit(
    bn1, 1st benefit;
    bn2, 2nd benefit;
    bn3, 3rd benefit;
    bn4, 4th benefit; 
)

employee(
    123, bill jones, 123 main st;
    321, alex baldwin, 222 state st;
)

employee_benefits(
    123, bn1;
    123, bn2;
    123, bn4; 
    321, bn3;
    321, bn4;
)

insurance(
    ins1, 1st insurance;
    ins2, 2nd insurance;
    ins3, 3rd insurance
)

insurance_benefits(
    ins1, bn1;
    ins1, bn2;
    ins2, bn1;
    ins2, bn3;
    ins2, bn4;
    ins3, bn2;
    ins3, bn4;
)
```

for employee 123. I need to select all insurances that have either the full list of benefits or a subset of the benefits held by the employee but not include instances that have benefits not held by the employee. in the above example, it would be ins1, and ins3.

is there a way to use outer join to accomplish the above?

Comment: hope this may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-parent-child-relationship-in-an-effective-and-easy-way

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with outer joins, but I think it's more intuitive to use `IN`-clauses with subqueries.

Benefits not held by employee `123`:

```
SELECT benefit_id
  FROM benefit
 WHERE benefit_id NOT IN
        ( SELECT benefit_id
            FROM employee_benefits
           WHERE employee_id = 123
        )
;
```

Insurance plans that offer any of the above benefits:

```
SELECT DISTINCT insurance_id
  FROM insurance_benefits
 WHERE benefit_id NOT IN
        ( SELECT benefit_id
            FROM employee_benefits
           WHERE employee_id = 123
        )
;
```

Insurance plans that don't offer any of the above benefits:

```
SELECT insurance_id
  FROM insurance
 WHERE insurance_id NOT IN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT insurance_id
            FROM insurance_benefits
           WHERE benefit_id NOT IN
                  ( SELECT benefit_id
                      FROM employee_benefits
                     WHERE employee_id = 123
                  )
        )
;
```

Comment: thank you much. this is really helpful. but it could be my lack of knowledge in the area that still causes me not to connect the dots. The main question is: how do I select all insurances with benefits that either exactly the same or constitute a subset of the benefits held by the employee but not more. i.e. must not include insurances with benefits that are not held by the employee. Does that make sense?

Comment: @KevinHandy: I *thought* it made sense -- the last query in my answer is the one that I thought you were describing. Am I misunderstanding something? Are you not seeing the results you expect?

Comment: sorry maybe I'm not explaining right. I am looking for insurance plans that either all or a subset of benefits already held by the employee. example:

Comment: sorry maybe I'm not explaining right. I am looking for insurance plans with benefits that constitute either the full or subset of the benefits held by the employee. if an insurance plan includes a benefit not held by the employee then I do not want to select it. but if the insurance plan includes benefits that are either the same or less than the ones held by the employee then I want to select those plans! does that make sense? the last query you have selects insurance plans that do not offer any of the benefits. I'm looking for the near opposite with one exception (either exact or less).

Comment: I *really* think that what you're describing is what this query does. (Or at least -- is what it's supposed to do. It's possible I messed up. Let me test . . .)

Comment: Yup, I've tested now, and it gives exactly the results you said you wanted: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d52b2/1

Comment: Great. you mean the last query (Insurance plans that don't offer any of the above benefits)! if so, I will test on the full database to find out the results.