# Recursive query to find all ancestor of a child

Tags: mysql

I have two tables listing the member of a family and their relationships:

MEMBERS

```
EMP_ID      Name
1          Great Grand Father
2          Grand Father
3          Father
4          Child1
5          Child2
```

RELATIONSHIP

```
MEM_ID      PAR_MEM_ID   
5                3
4                3
3                2
2                1
```

Now I want result as below:

```
G.G. Father      Grand Father     Father    Child1
G.G. Father      Grand Father     Father    Child2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, to ask something, you should show a little of what you've tried.

Comment: Samewhat duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-parent-child-relationship-in-an-effective-and-easy-way